# Create list of square powers of numbers in range using generator

Tags: python, range, generator

I'd like to rewrite this part of code using generator :

```
basic = []
for x in range(0,11):
    basic.append(x**2)
```

How can I do this ? Tried :

```
basic.append(x**2 for x in range(0,11))
```

but it raises syntax error in `x**2` part.

Comment: The code you pasted here doesn't raise a syntax error. (It won't do what you expect it to do though, it will append a lazy iterator instead of making a list from the items the said iterator yields)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'd be better off using list comprehension:

```
basic = [x*x for x in range(11)]
```

Comment: +1 And for the record, this is (at least conceptually, there's an implementation difference that makes this one slower) the same as `list(x*x for x in range(11))`.

Answer (score 9):

You are mistaken; your code doesn't produce a syntax error, it just does the wrong thing:

```
>>> basic = []
>>> basic.append(x**2 for x in range(0,11))
>>> basic
[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x01E9AD78>]
>>>
```

If you must use a generator:

```
>>> basic = list(x**2 for x in range(0,11))
>>> basic
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
>>>
```

It's simpler to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> basic = [x**2 for x in range(0,11)]
>>> basic
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `extend` not `append`.

```
>>> basic=[]
>>> basic.extend(x**2 for x in range(11))
>>> basic
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Better yet:

```
>>> basic = [x**2 for x in range(11)]
>>> basic
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> (x**2 for x in xrange(0,11))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb7387734>
```

or

```
>>> def gen():
...     for x in xrange(0,11):
...             yield x**2
... 
>>> gen
<function gen at 0xb738a0d4>
>>> gen()
<generator object gen at 0xb7387734>
>>>
```

Comment: OP doesn't have a problem writing a generator; he has a problem assembling the list.

Comment: @SilentGhost sure? becouse what's the sense in making list from generator in the same place?:)

Comment: Yes, doesn't make much sense. That's because he got confused by generator( expression)s when he tried to condense the generation of a list into a single expression.