# ValueError in range function (to print 3^(2^n)) in python

Tags: python, function, range

while trying to print the sequence of power(3,2^n), i.e, 3^2,3^4,3^8 , I tried using the following line using range function.Is it possible to use the range function to get the desired output? If so please let me know where did I went wrong.

```
for i in range(3,1000, i*(i-1)): print (i*i)
```

for example, the following output is expected for i=3,9,81

```
i*i:=9,81,6561
```

But the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#28>", line 1, in <module>
    for i in range(3,1000, i*(i-1)): print (i*i)
ValueError: range() arg 3 must not be zero
```

How can the step value be zero in this case?

Comment: Have you tried printing `i`?

Comment: because the `i` you create as part of the loop won't actually be set until the loop starts, so you're using `i` before it's defined in the `i*(i-1)` bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to build a list of all of your powers:

```
mylist = [3**(2**n) for n in range(1,10)]  # or whatever range
```

and then iterate through the comprehension to print all of your results if you want. You can do other stuff with your results in this loop instead of print them.

```
for item in mylist:
  print(item)  # print each item on a new line
```

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 2
while 3**i < 1000:
    print(3**i)
    i *= 2
```

Comment: This is just an example. You can change 1000 to 100000 or whatever you want

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure what you want to do is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636656/create-list-of-square-powers-of-numbers-in-range-using-generator). You want to be calling a list comprehension:

```
powersofthree = [3**(2**i) for i in range(10)]
```

which returns

```
[3, 9, 81, ... ]
```

Then you can print the result at you leisure.

Also, as many in the comments have pointed out, you used `i` before it was defined, which is why you encountered an error